# how can i check if my file is existed in python

Tags: python

I want to check the text file existence without using any function, does anyone know or have any example for it?

```
try:
    file = open('FizzBuzz.txt','w')
except:
    print('File already existed!')
else:
    for i in fizzbuzz:
        file.writelines(str(i)+'\n')
```

I did it like this, is it correct??

Comment: `file.writelines` should really be `file.write` here (`writelines` works, but only because strings are iterables of their characters, so it's effectively asking to write each individual character separately).

Comment: Well, did it work when you tried it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without using any function", as the `open` in your code is a function.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose saying "without using any function" you mean without actual trying to open the file for writing if it exists. If you just need a way to test whether file exists or no (without try/catch), you can use `os.path.isfile`:

```py
import os.path

file_path = 'FizzBuzz.txt'
if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
    file = open(file_path,'w')
    for i in fizzbuzz:
        file.writelines(str(i)+'\n')
else:
    print('File already existed!')
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to the comment by @JohnOmielan, there is an updated version to check also for the case when there is a directory (not file!) with the same name, e.g. 'FizzBuzz.txt':

```py
import os.path

file_path = 'FizzBuzz.txt'
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    file = open(file_path,'w')
    for i in fizzbuzz:
        file.writelines(str(i)+'\n')
else:
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        print(f'Cannot create new file {file_path}: file already existed!')
    else:
        print(f'Cannot create new file {file_path}: directory with the same name already exists!')
```

Comment: Note that, based on my understanding of what's in [os.path — Common pathname manipulations — Python 3.12.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), if the file path is to something like a directory (although unlikely with a name ending in `.txt`), then `isfile` will return false, but then `open` will fail. Instead, I believe it's more robust to check for anything existing there, using the `exists` function like [DouxDoux's answer](/a/78024459) does, although instead of printing 'File already exists`, it should perhaps be something like 'Path already exists' instead.

Comment: Thanks to your valuable comment, @JohnOmielan! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you are trying to do.

But try this :

```
import os

if not os.path.exists("path_to_file/FizzBuzz.txt"):
   with open('path_to_file/FizzBuzz.txt', 'w'): pass
else:
    print('File already exists')
```